# Enroll multiple times iOS Developer program

Tags: developer-program, mobile-device-management

Is it ok to enroll multiple times into the iOS Developer program to overcome the 100 device Limit ? I could not find anything about this within the Agreement. The Basic idear is that each Developer could enroll into the program and once as Company. Is this allowed ? If not it would be nice to point me to the appropriate resource as reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**. Although I couldn't find any specifics regarding the possibility of a Company having two or more *iOS Developer Program* accounts, in the [Enterprise Program FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enterprise.html) it is stated that:

> **If I am enrolled in the iOS Developer Enterprise Program, can I distribute my apps on the App Store?**
>
> No. The ability to distribute apps on the App Store is only available to developers enrolled in the standard iOS Developer Program. The iOS Developer Enterprise Program only allows you to distribute your apps to employees or members of your organization through Ad Hoc distribution.
>
> If your company is enrolled in the iOS Developer Enterprise Program but would also like to distribute your app(s) to customers on the App Store, you will need to enroll in the iOS Developer Program.

Which means that *Apple* has no problem with a Company having more than an account, which is confirmed (with a *regular program* too) by my personal experience.

Even more, in the specific case you present, as each developer would need to use his *personal legal name*, it would be, on practical purposes, as if you had hired a developer who was already enrolled into the program.

Comment: Just to be crystal clear: The Company has a iOS Developer Program Account (not enterprise). And now we would create one for me. Then it would be possible to test the app on 200 Devices. And there is no restriction against this way.

Comment: Legally, **no**. You'll have some issues with the *provisioning profiles* though, as you'll need to build the apps with different ones, which is a pain but not a restriction.